# String matrix models with c>1

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, specific-reference, conformal-field-theory, non-perturbative

Question 1: What is the status of string random matrix models (~ triangulated random surfaces) with c>1?

In my limited search, I have just come across a few papers by Frank Ferrari (in 2000-2002) on this. But, they applied, if I understand correctly, to a few cases with some specific kind of singularities in their moduli space or some higgs field. See his lecture at http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205171 and references therein.

---

On a slightly different note...
Question 2: How is the BFSS matrix model (and its derivatives, like the ones mentioned at [Good introductory text for matrix string theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/good-introductory-text-for-matrix-string-theory)) related to the random matrix models of triangulated worldsheets? My understanding is that the former is a nonperturbative formulation of some critical string theories, while the latter is a perturbative formulation of (noncritical only?) string theories. But, what are the similarities and connections between these two applications of random matrix theories?

PS: some references (especially some pedagogical ones) would also be of immense help!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the answer to question 1, but for question 2, the close relative of the matrix models are the 2-brane approximations of deWit, Hoppe, and Nicolai, who essentially give the same 1d matrix models as an approximate description of 11-dimensional supergravity 2branes many years before BFSS. The BFSS work discovers the a physical interpretation of this kind of description, in the D0 branes, but mathematically, the two models look the same.

Comment: Thanks for addressing question 2. But what is the relation between deWit, Hoppe & Nicolai matrix model (as used in BFSS etc) and Wigner random matrix model (as used in string worldsheet triangulation etc)?

Comment: Beats me! I never studied these. I'll look into it, and try to see.