# What are the good introductory resources for M-theory towards AdS/CFT?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, resource-recommendations, ads-cft

I see a list here with a section titled M-theory - http://www.superstringtheory.com/links/reviews.html

In there these two look promising, http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9607201 and http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802051

I would like to know if people have opinions of good starting points towards understanding M-branes and how they are used for constructing exact examples of AdS/CFT. [...I guess all exact AdS/CFT scenarios are M-theory constructions..]

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36303/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Well, **Becker, Becker, and Schwarz** *String theory and M-theory* probably fits your description, as it has a lot of great     text about AdS/CFT  and it's relation to M-theory, etc.      in the end.

Other than this, Lubos Motl also has an extraordinary summary of how  *matrix string theory* works (if you can get the intuition, you'll see a relation to AdS/CFT) works [here in this Physics.SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/good-introductory-text-for-matrix-string-theory/6426#6426).